# Why android application is not responding after a while loop by setting MediaPlayer to wait to finish?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am not really sure if the error is because of I have an alarm or while loop:

```
MediaPlayer mpChange;
MediaPlayer saved;
mpChange = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.change);
saved = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saved);
```

When I add a user I call a function and inside I informed the user message has saved by:

```
    saved.start();
```

After that I check if user has special meaning or not and again inform the user if it does not:

```
      else
      {

          /*Implement Audio Change*/
          while(saved.isPlaying() == true)
          {
             //Nothing except wait
              System.out.println("looop");
          }
          //saved.stop();
          System.out.println("finished");
          mpChange.start();
      }
```

Code is working fine and I don't get any error or conflict between the voices. However, I get an error with in my application which says:

> Application is not responding. Would you like to close?

I was not sure if it is the while loop or MediaPlayer.

Last output was:

```
looop
looop
looop
looop
finished
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you have to free media player to play another sound

Comment: @DigveshPatel How can I free a media player? Is this saved.release? If yes, I tired that but did not work

Comment: before start mpchange media player release saved media player

Comment: but best solution is implement oncomplete listner of media player so on complete of first you can start another one

Comment: so your ui is not stuck during that process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
saved.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mpChange.start();
    }
});

try this code in else part remove while loop
```